# Splitting a formula in table

Tags: tables, equations

I am a newbie in Latex and I have the following codes.

```
    \documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\newcommand{\hmi}{\hat{\mu}_i}
\newcommand{\hapi}{\hat{p}_i}
\newcommand{\hli}{\hat{\lambda_i}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
blah & blah blah \\
\hline
blah & $d_i = sign(y_i-\hmi) \sqrt{ 2\left\{ y_i \log \frac{ y_i}{\hmi} - (y_i - \hmi) \right\}} $ \\
\hline
blah & $ d_i = sign(y_i-\hmi) \left( 2\left\{ -y_i +y_i \log y_i -\log y_i ! - I(y_i=0)\log \left[ \hapi +(1-\hapi) e^{-\hli} \right] - I(y_i > 0)\log \left[ (1-\hapi) - \hli +y_i \log \hli -\log y_i ! \right] \right\} \right)^{1/2}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \caption{blah blah blah \label{tab:deviance}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I split that big formula into multiple lines in one cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}  % <-- added
    \usepackage{makecell}   % <-- added
    \usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
    \usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\newcommand{\hmi}{\hat{\mu}_i}
\newcommand{\hapi}{\hat{p}_i}
\newcommand{\hli}{\hat{\lambda_i}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
blah    & blah blah \\
    \hline
blah    & $d_i = sign(y_i-\hmi) \sqrt{ 2\left\{ y_i \log \frac{ y_i}{\hmi} - (y_i - \hmi) \right\}} $ \\
    \hline
blah    & $\begin{multlined}[t][0.8\linewidth]
    d_i = sign(y_i-\hmi) \Bigl(2\Bigl\{ -y_i +y_i \log y_i -\log y_i !
            - I(y_i=0)\log \Bigl[ \hapi +(1-\hapi) e^{-\hli} \Bigr]    \\[-1ex]
            - I(y_i > 0)\log \Bigl[ (1-\hapi)
            - \hli +y_i \log \hli -\log y_i ! \Bigr] \Bigr\}\Bigr)^{1/2}
           \end{multlined}$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\caption{blah blah blah 
    \label{tab:deviance}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For above code is necessary to add `mathtools` package. I also define math operator `sign`. For better spacing I also add package `makecell` and for table declare clls to be `\makegapedcells` with spacing `\setcellgapes{5pt}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much. this is even better than what I was looking for. Keep doing great. thanks

Comment: You are welcome! When you will have enough reputation, you can upvote answer (here a standard way to say "thank you"), now you can accept it ... Anyway, let mention: I didn't interfere in your definition of `\newcommand`s, however i think that last one should be `\newcommand{\hli}{\hat{\lambda}_i}`. Also see, if instead `hat` will look better `\widehat`. Also I don't understand, what means `\log y_i !`.